# Datastore - Resource contention in a single entity group -

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting lost on the following regarding the Datastore :

- It is recommended to denormalize data as the Datastore does not support join queries. This means that the same information is copied in several entities
- Denormalization means that whenever you have to update
  data, it must be updated in different entities
- But there is a limit of 1 write / second in a single entity group.

The problem I have is therefore the following :

- In order to update records, I open a transaction then
- Update all the required entities. The entities to be updated are within the same entity group but relate to different kinds
- I am getting a "resource contention" exception

==> **It seems therefore that the only way to update denormalized data is outside of a transaction**. But doing this is really bad as some entities could be updated whereas other entities wouldn't.

Am I the only one having this problem ? How did you solve it ?

Thanks,

Hugues

The (simplified version of the ) code is as follows :

```
Objectify ofy=ObjectifyService.beginTransaction();

try {
  Key<Party> partyKey=new Key<Party>(realEstateKey, Party.class, partyDTO.getId());

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //-- 1 - We update the party
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Party party=ofy.get(partyKey);
  party.update(partyDTO);

 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //-- 2 - We update the kinds which have Party as embedded field, all in the same entity group
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  //2.1 Invoices

  Query<Invoice> q1=ofy.query(Invoice.class).ancestor(realEstateKey).filter("partyKey", partyKey);
    for (Invoice invoice: q1) {
      invoice.setParty(party);
     ofy.put(invoice);
   }
  //2.2Payments 
  Query<Payment> q2=ofy.query(Payment.class).ancestor(realEstateKey).filter("partyKey", partyKey);
    for (Payment payment: q2) {
      payment.setParty(payment);
     ofy.put(payment);
   }
}

  ofy.getTxn().commit();
  return (RPCResults.SUCCESS);
}

catch (Exception e) {       
        final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(InternalServiceImpl.class.getName());       
        log.severe("Problem while updating party : " + e.getLocalizedMessage()); 
       return (RPCResults.FAILURE)  ;    
}

finally {
    if (ofy.getTxn().isActive()) {
      ofy.getTxn().rollback();
     partyDTO.setCreationResult(RPCResults.FAILURE);
    return (RPCResults.FAILURE) ;        
    }              
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code and stack trace of the error?

Comment: @mjibson Stack trace : com.plugimmo.web.server.internal.service.InternalServiceImpl requestUpdateLease: Problem while updating lease : too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.

Comment: If you post your code perhaps we can help more.

Comment: @mjibson. Sorry, forgot to add the code which I just did. I didn't quite understand what you meant by put_multi(). The second option (high-traffic site) is not true at this point of time. Only a few users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someones gets in the same issue.

The problem was in the party.update(partyDTO) where under some specific conditions, I was initiating another transaction.

What I learned today is that :

--> Inside a transaction, you are allowed to include multiple puts even getting over the 1 entity / second

--> However, you should take care not initiating another transaction within your transaction

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because multiple requests to update the same entity group are occurring in a short period of time, not because you are updating many entities in the same entity group at once.

Since you have not shown your code, I can assume one of two things are happening:

1. The method you describe above is not actually using a transaction and you are running `put_multi()` with many entities of the same entity group. (If I had to guess, it'd be this.)
2. You have a high-traffic site and many other updates are simultaneously occurring at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my code. You'll find the simplified version below :